# how to import extension to civicrm

Tags: civix

I would like to create an extension with civicrm. But I have a problem, although I could install civicrm and civix, I can not have where is the source code of the civicrm platform. 
I go to the directory/var/www/ and I see no repertory civic, for when I run localhost:8080/ in my browser it displays the platform. For both the documentation we ask to put the directory of the extension to the root of the civic project for this to be taken into account.
I create an extension with civix with the following command: civix generate: module com.example.myextension --license = AGPL-3.0. I did a hello world but I do not know how to see the hello appears on the platform.
in fact I am going in: administration> system setting> extension but I do not see how to import my extension into the platform

Comment: where the code is will depend on where you set up your cms - eg it might be at /var/www/<site>/all/modules/civicrm if it is drupal - but your extension folder is likely to be at /var/www/<site>/all/civicrm/extensions

Answer (score 2):

> in fact I am going in: administration> system setting> extension

With the above, I think you are able to access CiviCRM on the site. To see the extension in the `administration> system setting> extension` path, make sure you run the civix command in the extension directory, i.e -

1. Navigate to `Administer -> System Setting -> Directories`. Check the value of `Extensions Directory` input. This is where all your extension should be placed in.
2. Run the `civix` command from the terminal in the extension directory.
3. After the command runs successfully - you should be able to see your extension listed in `Administer -> System Setting ->  Extensions` path.

> I did a hello world but I do not know how to see the hello appears on the platform

You need to check how we can use extensions to extend the functionalities provided by CiviCRM. Check different [hooks](https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/hooks/) that can be used in `extension_name.php` file to add/modify results on the screen.